# Get full path and convert to constant

Tags: c#

Good day. I'm trying to remake dll for my needs. Namely, change the search path to dll.

DllImport:

```
[DllImport(NativeLibraryName, EntryPoint = "SteamAPI_Init", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern bool SteamAPI_Init();
```

Constant:

```
internal const string NativeLibraryName = @"steam_api64";
```

Get path to folder:

```
public static string SteamFolderPath()
{
      var r = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\Steam", "InstallPath", null);
      var rpath = r + "/steamapps/common/mygame/steam_api64";
      return r.ToString();
}
```

**When i try to do something like this, errors take off:**

```
internal const string NativeLibraryName = SteamFolderPath() + @"steam_api64";
```

I tried static readonly string. Nothing helps. Hope only for you) How to be? How to try to get the first path first, and then bring it to a constant?

p.s. I'm redoing the Steamworks.NET library.

Comment: A `const` have to be a literal value the compiler can fully evaluate at compile time. Pleast post the code and error you got with `static readonly` as this seems to be a better fit for your case.

Comment: Well you can't use const because its not a constant - you are calculating it in the method. What error do you get when you try static readonly string?

Comment: (Error from DllImport) - NativeLibraryName  "The argument of the attribute must be a constant expression, a typeof expression, or an expression for creating an array of the same type as the attribute parameter."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constant has to be known at compile time. It can't depend on the return value of a function.

You'll need to use `SetDllDirectory` to add the Steam path to the DLL search path:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);
string SteamPath = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\Steam", "InstallPath", null) + @"\steamapps\common\mygame\steam_api64";
SetDllDirectory(SteamPath); 

[DllImport("steam_api64")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern bool SteamAPI_Init();
```

Comment: System.DllNotFoundException: "Can not load the DLL" steam_api64 ": The specified module was not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" 
:(

Comment: Apologies, try adding @"\steamapps\common\mygame\steam_api64" to your SteamPath?

Comment: Oppps i forgot to add "\" and use "steamapps...". Lol... Works.. Thank you very much. One question...
If I embed this dll, where SetDllDirectory is used in my program, will the path in the entire program change to other dlls? Or this code only for this dll? (I could not really formulate the question, I hope you understood me)
p.s. Thanks again)

Comment: The directory will be added to the list of directories that DLLs are searched for in. It will be added quite high in the list, so there's a chance a Steam DLL could be found instead of a system DLL if they have the same name. The list and order are in the Remarks section at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx#code-snippet-1